# Return arrays from meteor mongo

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, mongodb, meteor

**[ajduke:bootstrap-tagsinput](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/)**

I am using the above package to create a tags system. I have used `<select multiple>` from the `True Input Value` from the link above and have inserted each tags as `Strings` within the `tag array`.

This is what my db looks like.

```
Posts
    tags              //Array
        [0] : sometag //String
        [1] : sometag //String
        [2] : sometag //String
                      //and so forth..
```

So my question is...
I want to return all the tags within a post to the following format, so that I can reuse it to show the tags when my users try to edit their posts.

**Wanted Format**

```
['sometag', 'sometag', 'sometag', and so forth]
```

### Edit1

this is what I've done so far.

**Post_Edit.js**

```
Template.postEdit.rendered = function() {
    myTags = Posts.findOne({_id: this._id}).tags.fetch(); //AAA
    
    $('.tagsinput').tagsinput('add', myTags); //From above link API
}
```

I've tried other methods for `//AAA` line but I am having no luck.I've tried things such as `Posts.findOne.map...` Maybe my english comprehension is not up to par but the documentations in meteor did not help me understand any better.

#### Edit 2

`Posts.findOne({_id: "ziZw3wLaxFyz3DYP4"}).tags`
I've tried putting this in the browser console and got the array in the format that I wanted.

But the problem is, it won't work in my app when I use it.

When I use `Posts.findOne({_id: this._id}).tags` in my postEdit.rendered, I get this browser console error. `Cannot read property 'tags' of undefined`
**Post_Edit.js**

```
Template.postEdit.rendered = function() {
    myTags = Posts.findOne({_id: this._id}).tags;

    
    $('.tagsinput').tagsinput('add', myTags); //From above link API
}
```

What I don't understand is why is it working in browser console but not my Template.postEdit.rendered?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this? What research have you done? Right now it looks like you just ask for the solution without investing yourself.

Comment: @Kyll I've invested the past few hours to trying to figure this out. I'll update my question so I show what I have failed to achieved. I haven't put my input here cause I am pretty sure I'm on the wrong direction.

Comment: Thanks. It's extremely important for us. Even if you think you've gone the wrong way it will show that you have made an investment in the matter (and thus are not only asking for free code), and we can see your reasoning, what went wrong and why, and redirect you to the better way(s). it may also help future readers learn from your failures!

Comment: @Kyll Thank you for the pointer. I will do that from now on for future questions as well. I've only started programming not so long ago, and I'm studying by myself in a country that does not favor meteor or new technology as much as other countries. 90% of people here use php and mysql. I'm always greatful for the answer I get in Stackoverflow!

Comment: It could be that the `Posts` collection is not ready when you try to query on it... But in that case, `Posts.findOne({_id: this._id}).tags` would throw. Does it throw, then?

Comment: @Kyll I think it might be that it is could be not ready. I think I've read before that in order to fetch data from collections usings Template.rendered, I'd have to use `Deps.autorun` or a work around. Since I didn't know how to use the above, I decided to find a way using helpers. I got it figured out! Answered below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've approached a completely different way to figure this out.
But I'd still like to know why my method did not work...

**post_edit.js**

```
Template.postEdit.helpers({
    tags: function(){
        Posts.findOne({_id:this._id}).tags;
    }
});
```

**post_edit.html**

```
<select class=tagsinput id="tagsinput" data-role="tagsinput">
    {{#each}}
        <option value="{{this}}">{{this}}</option>
    {{/each}}
```

Comment: Your `rendered` callback (by the way, if you do a `meteor update` it will be `onRendered`) is not reactive: It runs once. The helpers however are reactive, they will re-run each time the reactive data used in their body changes; and the client-side collection queries are reactive.

Comment: @Kyll So does this mean that rendered initiates before the data is loaded?

Comment: @Kyll And for the `onRendered` callback, I'm still using rendered because I noticed some of my packages would break if I used `onRendered`. I know it is still supported. I just hope the packages update soon. (I don't really know why its breaking but changing onRendered to rendered would fix things...)

Comment: `rendered` initiates as soon as possible, it won't care about data AFAIK.

Comment: @Kyll Thank you :) I have learned a lot. I will need to learn how to use `Deps.autorun` and its benefits and disadvantages. But for now, I'm very happy I figured this out! I will avoid using data related code for `rendered` for the time being. Always appreciate your comments on `Meteor` related topics.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that your variable myTags is undefined when Template.postEdit.rendered is called because the Posts database has not finished loading when your function is called.

```
myTags = Posts.findOne({_id: this._id}).tags.fetch(); //AAA
```

**Solution**
There are multiple strategies including:

1. Updating DOM after subscription completes
   http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/Blaze-TemplateInstance-subscribe
2. Re-run the function when Collection changes
   http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_autorun

   ```
   Template.postEdit.rendered = function() {
      Tracker.autorun(function () {  ** NEW LINE **
         myTags = Posts.findOne({_id: this._id}).tags; 

         $('.tagsinput').tagsinput('add', myTags); 
      } ** NEW LINE **
   }
   ```